# Operações atômicas em ARM sem Visual Studio

Tags: android, c, assembly, arm

Quando programando em C/C++ na arquitetura x86 e x86-64 (AMD64) e utilizando o compilador da Microsoft que vem com o Visual Studio, existem duas funções intrínsecas para realizar operações atômicas, `_InterlockedCompareExchange32` e `_InterlockedIncrement32`, que são implementadas através das instruções assembly `lock cmpxchg` e `lock xadd`, respectivamente.

Olhando a documentação no MSDN, na seção [ARM Intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875058.aspx), li que o compilador da Microsoft também tem essas duas funções intrínsecas para a arquitetura ARM.

Obviamente essas funções na arquitetura ARM não serão substituídas pelas instruções assembly `lock cmpxchg` e `lock xadd`, visto que ela não possui tais instruções.

Como implementar as funções `_InterlockedCompareExchange32` e `_InterlockedIncrement32` (pode ser em C ou em assembly), de modo que seja compilável pelo compilador ARM que vem com o NDK do Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa, encontrei um material disponibilizado pelo Google (impossível de reproduzir aqui, por ser enorme) chamado [Symmetric Multi-Processor Primer for Android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html).

Em diversas partes [do material](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html) existem comparações entre as arquiteturas x86 e ARM, oportunamente explicando alguma possível diferença entre seus comportamentos (principalmente pelo fato da arquitetura ARM não possuir algumas instruções que a arquitetura x86 possui).

Devido a uma série de fatores, todos explicados [no material sobre SMP](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html), a solução mais segura/rápida para implementar mecanismos de sincronização no Android (em C/C++) é utilizando a biblioteca [POSIX Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) ou [Pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads), cuja documentação se encontra [aqui](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html).

Mencionei isso na resposta, pois apesar de não ter dito na pergunta, meu objetivo final com as funções `_InterlockedCompareExchange32` e `_InterlockedIncrement32` era justamente implementar mecanismos de sincronização bem triviais.

Durante a pesquisa, eu também encontrei quais são as funções que compilam no NDK do Android e realizam as funcções atômicas análogas às que estava procurando: `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` e `__sync_fetch_and_add`, respectivamente.

Elas são *built-in functions* do compilador GCC, e estão explicadas na documentação do próprio GCC: [Built-in functions for atomic memory access](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

De acordo com [esse tópico do Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/gkjXkvZKlQQ), todas elas funcionam sem problemas com o compilador do NDK do Android.